# Не могу понять, почему php принимает переменную sessionx с ajax как null?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Вот код ajax:

```
var sessionx = prompt('ВВЕДИТЕ ID АККАУНТА', '');

$.ajax({
                url: 'show.php',
                type: 'post',
                data: {'session': sessionx},
                success: function(data) {             $.getJSON("show.php",
    function(data){
        $("#username").html(data.username);
        $("#usermoney").html(data.usermoney); 
        alert(data.userm);
});
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
```

Show.php:

```
<?php

$filename = $_POST["session"];

    $username = file_get_contents("users/$filename/name.txt");
    
    $usermoney = file_get_contents("users/$filename/money.txt");
    
    $arr = array('username' => $username,'usermoney' => $usermoney,'userm' => $filename);
    
    echo json_encode($arr);
    
?>
```

Я прописал возвращаемую переменную в alert и она равняется null только после того как побывает в show.php. помогите пожалуйста разобраться, заранее спасибо.

Comment: замени `type: 'post',`  на `method: 'POST',`

Comment: стоп. так у тебя два раза вызывается show.php. зачем-то в success первого аякса делается второй запрос getJSON. Зачем?

Comment: Заменил, но всё равно не работает, приходит null.

Comment: Второй запрос идёт на получение отработанных данных в show.php, тоесть я забираю переменные, которые там сформировались, это работает когда я там в php задаю переменную session, а вот когда ajax её туда передаёт show.php почему-то не принимает её

Comment: Понятно, вы не знаете как работает php. Так это не работает.

Comment: Подскажите как сделать, что бы работало.

Comment: php в себе не может ничего хранить. как только к скрипту постучались - он сделал свою работу и "умер". В следующий раз когда к нему стучаться он опять в старом состоянии.

Comment: sessionx в кавычках передаёте как строку, уберите кавычки

Comment: "как сделать, что бы работало" --- почитать книгу для начала по php. Например Котеров - PHP 7,0 в подлиннике. А потом начать писать код..... вкратце - самое простое и глупое - включить в скрипте сессию. Более правильное - зависит от задачи

Comment: Pavel, ковычки убрал, всё равно не пашет

Comment: Я знаю как работает php, в курсе, что отработал и умер, но в данной проблеме он отрабатывает только тогда, когда переменная задана в самом php, а значит проблема на стороне ajax, который не может передать переменную sessionx в php как session, что бы тот её установил как $filename.

Comment: ошибаетесь. напишите  `console.log(data);` ДО $.getJSON  и посмотрите в консоль

Comment: второй запрос нифига тебе не возратит, потому что для него не существует $_POST["session"]